# Solve the limit without using L'Hopitals $\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+7}-2}{2x^2+3x-5\:}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+7}-2}{2x^2+3x-5\:}\right)$$

I think I need to do in the numerator by multiplying the difference of cubes.
$\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{x+7}-2\right)\cdot \left(\sqrt[3]{\left(x+7\right)^2}+2\sqrt[3]{x+7}+4\right)}{\left(2x^2+3x-5\right)\:\cdot \left(\sqrt[3]{\left(x+7\right)^2}+2\sqrt[3]{x+7}+4\right)}\right)=\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{x+7-8}{\left(2x^2+3x-5\right)\:\cdot \left(\sqrt[3]{\left(x+7\right)^2}+2\sqrt[3]{x+7}+4\right)}\right)=\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{x-1}{\left(2x^2+3x-5\right)\:\cdot \left(\sqrt[3]{\left(x+7\right)^2}+2\sqrt[3]{x+7}+4\right)}\right)$

Here's what to do with the denominator?
and whether I chose the idea of a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Just note that $$2x^2+3x-5=(x-1)(2x+5)$$

Comment: exactly !! thank!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+7}-2}{2x^2+3x-5\:}\right)
& = \lim _{t\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{\left(t+1\right)+7}-2}{2\left(t+1\right)^2+3\left(t+1\right)-5\:}\right)
\\& = \lim _{t\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{t+8}-2}{2t^2+7t}\right)
\\& = \lim _{t\to 0}\left(\frac{2+\frac{1}{12}t-\frac{1}{288}t^2+o\left(t^2\right)-2}{2t^2+7t}\right)
\\& = \color{red}{\frac{1}{84}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Solved with substitution $\color{red}{t = x-1}$ and Taylor expansion